# When is a dependency injected object initialized in WPF?

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection

I'm trying to wrap my head around the dependency injection concept in WPF. If I have a Dialog that has a ViewModel defined as being dependency injected, at what point during runtime is the dependency injected ViewModel initialized and given a value? Is it during the Initialize() method that is called in the Constructor of the Dialog?

```
public partial class LoginDialog
    {

        private LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;

        [Dependency]
        public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel
        {
            get { return _loginViewModel; }
            set
            {
               ...
            }
        }

        public LoginDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand that Dependency Injection, and WPF are not related at all?  Other than you can use DI in a WPF application (as you can with any other), but you can also write a WPF application that uses no DI at all.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla Yes, I understand they are not related. I just mention it to give some context. I'm really just trying to understand when a Dependency Injected variable is initialized during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is: It depends (no pun intended).  It depends on a lot of things, which DI framework are you using (Unity, Ninject, etc)?  In Unity (I have more experience with this one) you have to define what the lifetime scope of an object is, and depending on it's lifetime, you may get things done at different times.

To try to be more specific:  Generally, a dependency property as you demonstrated there, will be "set" when the object on which it is defined is instantiated.  So when your `LoginDialog` is instantiated, the `LoginViewModel` should be set.

Comment: +1.  This is true of all the major DI Frameworks, although some use singleton lifestyle by default (e.g. Windsor) and some use per request by default (e.g. Structuremap).